# Phone lists saved WiFi network that I do not recognize

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I know my phone will not store WiFi hotspots unless I connect to them, but I've noticed one on my phone that I have no recollection of ever connecting or saving. It's out of range yet saved on the list.

I am wondering if there is anyway this is possible. Obviously if WiFi is on it will scan whatever is around, but will not store any of them unless told to. I'm wondering why I have one stored that I've never connected to or saved. Nobody else has used my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Some other people have had a similar problem:

- http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/615395-wifi-keeps-auto-connecting.html

It is possible that your phone connected to it because it is an open network, which means that no password is required to connect. You can disable this feature by going to:

Settings --> Wireless & Network settings --> Wifi Settings

There should be a checkbox for automatically joining an open wifi network, just uncheck it.

If your device does not have a checkbox for this, then your device does not have that function and it is not the source of your problem.

It is also possible that you joined the network on accident. Most phones have a setting that sends a notification when an open network is available. If you click on the notification it will connect to the network.

---

If you want your device to forget a network, then just go to wifi settings, then click on the remembered network and select forget.